# extracting specific lines between first and second repated strings in text file

Tags: text-processing

My data file looks like:

```
#cP2019  6 30  0  0  0.00000000     192 ORBIT IGS14 BHN ESOC                    
## 2060      0.00000000   900.00000000 58664 0.0000000000000                    
+   54   G18G14G13G28G21G11G22G20G16G19G23G02G31G17G12G15G29                    
+        G07G05G25G01G30G24G27G06G09G03G26G08G10G32R10R12R13                    
+        R19R20R01R22R24R23R16R04R08R03R07R02R18R21R09R17R14                    
+        R11R05R15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0                    
+          0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0                    
++         7  4  4  5  5  4  5  5  5  4  4  5  4  4  5  4  5                    
++         4  4  5  5  5  5  4  4  5  6  5  5  5  4  6  6  5                    
++         6  6  6  5  5  6  6  5  5  6  5  6  5  5  5  5  6                    
++         6  6  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0                    
++         0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0                    
%c M  cc GPS ccc cccc cccc cccc cccc ccccc ccccc ccccc ccccc                    
%c cc cc ccc ccc cccc cccc cccc cccc ccccc ccccc ccccc ccccc                    
%f  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.00000000000  0.000000000000000                    
%f  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.00000000000  0.000000000000000                    
%i    0    0    0    0      0      0      0      0         0                    
%i    0    0    0    0      0      0      0      0         0                    
/* CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  
*  2019  6 30  0  0  0.00000000  
....... data ......
....... data ......
....... data ......
*  2019  6 30  0 15  0.00000000   
....... data ......
....... data ......
....... data ......
*  2019  6 30  0 30  0.00000000    
....... data ......
....... data ......
....... data ......

and goes on like this ...
```

I need to extract the lines between first and second date for each data file. I can apply the following code to extract these lines as follows:

```
sed -n '/*  2019  6 30  0  0/,/*  2019  6 30  0 15 /p' esu20601_00.sp3 > extract_1
```

But the dates and the locations of the data are different for each file. So I need to extract the lines between the first `*  2019` and second `*  2019` for each file. How can I do this using codes?

Comment: Is this really an IGS SP3c file? if so, the location of the first epoch header should be unambiguous (although apparently it should be line 23 rather than line 20 as shown in your example - there should be 4 comment lines rather than just 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could no doubt be more sophisticated, but with primitive python tools:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
# open/read file
f = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
# find first line, holding *  2019
first = f.find("*  2019")
# find second line, holding *  2019
nxt = f.find("*  2019", first + 1)
# print out text between the two
text = f[first:nxt].splitlines()[1:]
for l in text:
    print(l)
```

- Copy the code into an empty file, save it as `findsection.py`
- Run it by:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/findsection.py <datafile>
  ```

Output (from first section):

```
....... data ......
....... data ......
....... data ......
```

Of course you could make it collect data from a whole dir, write to a new file etc, etc.